# Adding Java Servlet to Visual Studio

Tags: java, visual-studio, servlets

I would like to ask if there is any possibility to include a Java Servlet in a Visual Studio solusion?

Comment: If you have the source, there's always IKVM.

Comment: My question is, that I have given an existing project in Visual Studio - Visual Studio solusion, and I want to create a Java Servlet so a code from within the solusion will access that servlet and use it.

Comment: My guess is http://www.ikvm.net/

Comment: Java has its own project format (depends on the Java IDE or build system such as ANT/Maven you use). Visual Studio has no way to understand such Java IDE projects or build system file format, unless you write an VS addin (or someone else created it in the past). Therefore, technically it is possible but you need to do some Internet search first. IKVM won't help in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Is your existing project in Java !

Servlets are deployed on server. So no matter what language you client code is, they can access servlets with HTTP.

Note : servlets are not like other normal classes, and they are not supposed to be used as normal classes - By that I mean, servlets are not supposed to be instantiated explicitely, you can not call methods on servlets directly.

If you intention is to have your code interact with servlets, then your code can act as http client and can invoke servlets using HTTP.

If your intention is to use servlets as like other classes, no that's not possible.

If you intention is to write and develop servlets in Visual Studio solusion - then it depends on weather Visual Studio solusion supports java or not.

Comment: OK, I see, my goal is to invoke that java servlet from javascript that exists in the current visual studio solusion: there is a code in there: `var sURL = getUniqueSid("MessageComposer_HTTP.aspx?F=" + f + "&FB=" + fb);` and I want him to access my Servlet instead of the asp page, so what should I do?

Comment: In the aspx code, the programmer wrote: `doc.Save(Response.OutputStream)` and in my servlet, I wrote: 
`Source source = new DOMSource(doc);
   StreamResult responseResults = new StreamResult(response.getOutputStream());
   TransformerFactory Stringfactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
   Transformer transformer = Stringfactory.newTransformer();
   transformer.transform(source, responseResults);`
 the output that I see on the screen is exacly the same, but still it appears that I receive no answer from the servlet.

Answer (score 0):

IKVM won't be of any use for you, it requires development to develop the overwrite methods needed and even though will be tricky

Answer (score -1):

http://www.jnbridge.com/ Just take a look at it. Maybe it could help you.